# Pass data from parent component to child | React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I wonder how I can access my props item in my doorsItem component. My code in the parent is this:
`const doors = this.props.doors.data.map(item => <DoorsItem item={item} />)`

My `DoorsItem` component looked like this before:

```
const DoorsItem = ({ item, customer }) =>
  <Grid>
    <Row key={item._id}>
      <Col style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <ul className="door-list">
          <li className="door-flex-container">
            <div className="door-flex-item-1">
              <h4 className="title-text-container">
                {item.address.street} // Can use 'item' here
```

But I wanted to connect it with redux so I ended up with this:

```
class DoorsItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <ul className="door-list">
              <li className="door-flex-container">
                <div className="door-flex-item-1">
                  <h4 className="title-text-container">
                    {/* How can I use it here? */}
                  </h4>
                </div>
```

So I was wondering what’s the best way to access the `item` props in my new coded component?

Thanks for reading and sorry for the nooby question!

Comment: There is no need to make it a class based component. Functional components can also be connected. Anyways you can just access the props via `this.props;`. Insert the line `const {item, customer} = this.props` before your return statement and you will be able to access it equivalent to your functional component.

Comment: So adding redux with connect won’t be a problem if change it back?

Comment: Yes you can. As long as your component does not use state or lifecycle functions there is not need to make it a class. The `connect()` function doesn't care about if it is a class or a function.

Comment: Well then I will change it back haha thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `<DoorsItem item={item} />`, you're assigning the `item` prop, which means that within this component you can use it like `this.props.item` or even better `const { item } = this.props;` and use the `item` local variable later. So for example:

`const { item } = this.props;
return <span>this is the {item} you're looking for</span>`

More information about that on [the official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html).

Usually, when using class based components, we should define the `propTypes` and `defaultProps`. This gives us a better understanding of the class-based component's `props` to use and provides validation for `props` to be inserted. More information [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) (warning: moved to a separate package since React v15.5).

Finally, [you can use `context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), which is not the recommended way but sometimes can be helpful.

Comment: You can access context in functional components too. It's just the second parameter after props. Although it is discouraged to use it except for maybe libraries like redux or react-router because the api is likely to change in the future. Also you can and should define PropTypes on functional components too.

Comment: That's really helpful @trixn Personally ,I only go with class-based components because they're easier to organise and the scope for the `this` keyword is clearer